# Как сделать историю навигации перехода по меню?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть простое меню с 3 пунктов(в дальнешем их будет возможно больше), нужно чтоб при нажатии на кнопку go происходил переход вперед по истрии вперед , а при нажатии на кнопку "bg" возврат на шаг назад.

Пример: Если пользователь кликнул на пункт "meny_1" потом на "meny_2" и на "meny_3" то он сделал активними все эти три пункта по очереди. Но когда он нажал на кнопку "bg" то он вернулсяб на предыдущие меню. И при на жати на кнопку "go" пользователь перейдет на шаг вперед.

Возможно ли это реализовать на jquery?

Вот пример моего кода с переходам:

```js
$(".nav").click(function() {

  $(".nav").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

```css
ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">go</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="nav" href="#">meny_1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="nav" href="#">meny_2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="nav" href="#">meny_3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">bk</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @lexxl массивы для слабаков?))) Ну ты предложил какой то ад на самом деле... Просто при клике, записывать в массив `history`, который может лежать в `localStorage` например.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".nav").click(function() {

  $(".nav").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

});
```

```css
ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
ul > li > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="window.history.forward()">go</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="nav" href="#">meny_1</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="nav" href="#">meny_2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="nav" href="#">meny_3</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript: void(0);" onclick="window.history.back()">bk</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```